# Determine possible coordinates for point $P$ on the terminal arm of angle

Tags: trigonometry

a) If angle $\theta\\$ lies in Quadrant II and 
$\sin \theta ={3 \over {\sqrt {45} }}$. Determine possible coordinates for point $P$ on the terminal arm of angle $\theta$.

b) Determine the Quadrant in which angle $\theta$ is located if $\cos\theta < 0$ and $\tan \theta > 0$.

How would I do such a problem?

Comment: Apply the Pythagorean Theorem sin²t+cos²t=1. Substitute your given sine value and calculate the cosine value. You know the quadrant, hence the sign of the cosine value.

Comment: I believe you are asking 2 different questions. Also, the tag of calculus is not appropriate. Perhaps trigonometry?

Comment: SIN^(2)2+COS^2(2)=1?

Comment: much apolgizes ;

Comment: If you draw the sine value in a right triangle: with respect to angle theta, the opposite is 3, the hypotenuse is √45 and so through the Pythagorean Theorem you find the adjacent to be 6. Now if you know the definition of cosine, it should not be difficult anymore

Comment: @user73122 You have many questions asked but very few votes cast and very few answers "accepted"... (continued)

Comment: @user73122 Just a friendly reminder in case you don’t know how the site works: after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "upvote" and/or "accept" the answer by clicking the up arrow and the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question and will encourage others to answer your other questions. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1):

For part a, $\sin\theta=\frac{3}{\sqrt{45}}=\frac{3}{3\sqrt{5}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and since we know that the sine of an angle is the opposite over the hypotenuse we can imagine a triangle whose hypotenuse is $\sqrt{5}$ and whose opposite side is $1$. The Pythagorean theorem tells us that the adjacent side is then $\sqrt{\sqrt{5}^2-1^2}=\sqrt{5-1}=2$.

Since we are given that the point must be in the second quadrant, this gives a possible point of $(-2,1)$. Note that any positive multiple of this will also work, e.g. $(-4,2)$.

For part b, we use the fact that the cosine function is negative in the second and third quadrants and the tangent is positive in the first and third quadrants. Therefore, $\theta$ must be in the third quadrant for both conditions to be satisfied.